# springboot configuring mutiple yaml files and load them based on env param

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, yaml, properties-file

I have to tweak a springboot application that has application.yaml file where the app properties are configured.

The properties are mapped using annotation in java class file to read the value @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="propName")

Now the requirement is i need to have another file called application-profile-2.yml and rename application.yml to application-profile-1.yml, these files are needed to be picked up by the parmater -Drun-profile=profile1 when i run/build the application

how do i dynamically have my app to load application-profile-2.yml when i pass the param -Drun-profile=profile2 during my build/run command ?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: apologies, just realized i typed it half, i've edited my question again, hope it makes some sense now :)

Comment: Checkout https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single yaml file. Yaml allows you to inherit and override sections. The properties for profile2 will override the `username` and `password`, but inherit `url`.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb
    username: username
    password: password

---

spring:
  profiles: profile2
  datasource:
    username: username2
    password: password2
```

Comment: but what is the way of having multiple yml files ?

Comment: application-{profileName}.yml is what you are looking for.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-profile-specific